# How to implement File transfer in c# Windows app using jabber net

Tags: c#, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm develop a chat application with jabber net and ejabberd. i done with one to one chat conversation with xmpp. now going to implement file transfer between the JID's

i refereed with documentation about oob transfer in xmpp (xep-0066).
i followed with this document, oob feature not listed in server response.

```
<iq type='get'
    from='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony'
    to='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'
    id='disco1'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
</iq>
```

**Expected:**

```
<iq type='result'
    from='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'
    to='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony'
    id='disco1'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'>
    ...
    **<feature var='jabber:iq:oob'/>
    <feature var='jabber:x:oob'/>**
    ...
  </query>
</iq>
```

OOB feature not enabled in my server response. how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

XEP-0060 is a client protocol and independent from the server, therefore you should send query to your contact (using FullJID, i.e. containing resource part: `/resource`) and it should return information whether it supports or not OOB transfer.